Ant Design Components Turning Black in Production After Next.js Build with Tailwind CS
When developing a Next.js site with Tailwind CSS and Ant Design, I encountered an unusual issue after building the site for production. All components from Ant Design, which appeared as expected during development, had their colors changed to black in production. For example, input fields that were white during development turned black in the production build.
my tailwind.config.ts file
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  important: true,
};

AntdRegistry.tsx
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";
import type Entity from "@ant-design/cssinjs/es/Cache";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";

const StyledComponentsRegistry = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const cache = React.useMemo<Entity>(() => createCache(), []);
  useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
    <style
      id="antd"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: extractStyle(cache, true) }}
    />
  ));
  return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>;
};

export default StyledComponentsRegistry;

Providers.tsx
"use client";

import { store } from "@/redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "./AntdRegistry";

const Providers = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Providers;

